# How to share my updatable Cache across mappers and reducers in MapReduce?

Tags: caching, mapreduce, mapper, reducers

I want to share my Cache across Mapper/reducers. Using DistributedCache sharing can be achieved but its read only, so not fit for my req. My requirement is such that the cache will be updated by the map method, if it gets new value not already present in cache. The cache size will not be more than 500 elements. I have seen some solution here on stackoverflow but still some doubts. Any suggestion /hints for achieving this.